# Adding comma to jQuery animated numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, custom-scrolling

I'm using a jQuery script from here.
So far it works great, but the only thing that I'm wondering about is how to go about getting a comma into one of the values.

Since the number animate up when you scroll, it's tricky to get the browser to check what the integer is after the fact. I've read a bunch of posts that will add a comma (in this case I'm trying to get `100,000`) but it won't work since the browser can't see that integer initially (starts at 0).

Here's the script that I'm using to invoke the animaition when you scroll down the page:

```
$(function () {
    var fx = function fx() {
      $(".stat-number").each(function (i, el) {
        var data = parseInt(this.dataset.n, 10);
        var props = {
          "from": {
            "count": 0
          },
          "to": {
            "count": data
          }
        };
        $(props.from).animate(props.to, {
          duration: 500 * 1,
          step: function (now, fx) {
            $(el).text(Math.ceil(now));
          },
          complete:function() {
            if (el.dataset.sym !== undefined) {
              el.textContent = el.textContent.concat(el.dataset.sym)
            }
          }
        });
      });
    };

    var reset = function reset() {
      console.log($(this).scrollTop())
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 950) {
        $(this).off("scroll");
        fx()
      }
    };

    $(window).on("scroll", reset);
  });
```

It takes the value from the data attribute `data-n` in the HTML and then works it's magic from there. If I have `100,000` in the `data-n` attribute then it cuts it short at `100` when the numbers animate.

So yeah, I'm not sure if I need to amend this script so it can accommodate for the comma in the data attribute or if there is something else I might need to do after the fact?

Comment: Of course it will cut off everything in the decimals, you are using `parseInt`

Comment: @LucaKiebel - any better way instead of using parseInit?

Comment: there is `parseFloat`, but 100.000 *is* 100, so that wouldn't really matter

Comment: @LucaKiebel - Ok. Well it's not so much the decimal that I'm using. It's the comma. The data that I'm getting out is `100,000`. I can strip the comma out with PHP, but then when animation hit, it rolls up the number to 100000 without the comma. I'm not sure if I can use something other than `parseInt` to get it to add that comma back in or if there is a different way I need to go about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after digging through it a bit more, I was able to come up with a solution.

I found this:

```
  $.fn.digits = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
      $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
    })
  }
```

and then added an addtional class in my HTML.

I then hooked into the `complete:function` and added:

```
$(".class-i-added").digits();
```

to the end of the animation.

Overall, that *appears* to provide the result that I am looking for.
Since I only need to attribute it to one number (so far) it works as it should.